# CORS preflight with SessionAuthenticationModule

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, cors, wif, ripple

I could really use help with this one.  In a nutshell, I'm trying to make a cross-domain (CORS) request from a locally hosted Cordova app to an ASP.NET Web API also hosted locally.  The challenge is that my client app and Web API are both using different ports hence the need for CORS support.  I've tried several different things to circumvent this but no luck so far.  Here are the specifics:

- My Cordova app is built with VS Tools for Apache Cordova and is running in Chrome via the Ripple Emulator.  The challenge here is that the emulator auto-assigns the port and I can't seem to find a way to override that.  In other words, if I can change the port to match the one used for my Web API then I can work around the CORS limitation temporarily.
- My Web API is CORS-enabled via a reference to System.Web.Http.Cors and the following startup code:

```html
public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");  // note: the '*' values are temporary for testing purposes
      config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
  }
```

- My client app is issuing a preflight request since my content type is required to be application/json.  Attempting to add the withCredentials flag set to true has no effect - i.e. my bearer token is never sent during the preflight request.
- My Web API is secured via Windows Identity Foundation.  Specifically, I have a custom SessionAuthenticationModule that's authenticating every request regardless of whether or not it's CORS-related.  I’ve had limited success with trying to customize the module (below) such that I can get it to accept a preflight request but the follow-up POST from my client app is never submitted.  Should I run this logic asynchronously?

```html
public class CustomSessionAuthenticationModule : SessionAuthenticationModule
  {
    private const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
    private const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
    private const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    private const string Origin = "Origin";

    protected override void InitializeModule(HttpApplication context)
    {
      base.InitializeModule(context);

      context.BeginRequest += ApplicationOnBeginRequest;
    }

    private static void ApplicationOnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

      if (application.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && application.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Options.ToString())
      {
        application.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        application.Response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, application.Request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

        string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", application.Request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
        {
          application.Response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks all for any suggestions you can offer that might help solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others who may be having a similar issue, I made some progress via a workaround.  Here's what I did:

- Created a new virtual application in IIS under the same top-level site that's hosting my Web API.  This new application points to the source for my Cordova app.  Since they're both under the same site and port, no CORS preflight requests are issued.
- I also installed the [Ripple Emulator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fripple-emulator-beta%2Fgeelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc%3Fhl%3Den&ei=khH-VOqUN8GqgwT8zYL4DQ&usg=AFQjCNFvdPZt538_ORTmkOND9kUo_bR-1Q&bvm=bv.87611401,d.eXY) in Chrome then clicked the Enable button from the toolbar drop down, browsed to my new site and selected Mobile Web as the default platform.

**Update 8/12/15:**
The missing piece is adding the following entry to authorization section of system.web in web.config:

```
<allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
```

As long as the custom SAM falls back to the base OnAuthenticateRequest method for preflight requests then everything works correctly.